# how to get the path of the class in scala maven project

Tags: scala, path, directory

here i have a scala maven project,the directory as follows:
   [image]

I want to get the **HelloWorld.scala**'s path in the **Main.scala**.
what should I do?

Comment: What's the goal? Path or package? What have you tried?

Comment: i have use the " System.getProperty("user.dir")"  and java "getClass().getResource() ". but they do not work.My goal is to parse the source code in HelloWorld.scala.

Comment: The sources are not copied to the JAR. If you don't need to access the compiled `HelloWorld` class, you could put the `HelloWorld.scala` source file it in the `resources` folder; then it should be possible to load it using `getClass().getResource()`.